# How can I remove the multiple display of ``nomineename`` ( which is highlighted) from the below iterating function

Tags: reactjs

How can I remove the multiple display of  `nomineename` ( which is highlighted) from the below iterating function.
[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
const moment = require('moment');

const NominationList = () => {
    const [nominationGroup, setNominationGroup] = useState({});
    const uniqueName = [];
    const isMounted = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        isMounted.current = true;
        return () => isMounted.current = false;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/nominationgroup');
                if (isMounted.current) {
                    setNominationGroup(res.data);
                    console.log("Nomination data from server :" + res.data);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="leftNavItem">
                <a><Link to={'/dashboard'} className="nav-link"> <b>Dashboard</b> </Link></a>
            </div>
            <h1 className="header"><b>Nomination List</b></h1>
            <div className="wrap">
                <div id="sidebar-left">
                    <th>Nominee name</th>
                </div>
                <div id="main-content">
                    <th>Reason for Nomination</th>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar-right">
                    <th>Date</th>
                </div>
            </div>

            {

                Object.keys(nominationGroup).map(nomineename  =>(
                <div className="wrap">
                            <div key={nominationGroup[nomineename].nomineename} id="sidebar-left">
                                {nominationGroup[nomineename].nomineename}
                            </div>
                            <div id="main-content">
                                <li key={nominationGroup[nomineename].description} className="nomlistdata">{nominationGroup[nomineename].description}</li>
                            </div>
                            <div key={nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt} id="sidebar-right">
                                {moment(nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}
                            </div>
                    <hr></hr>
                </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    )

}
export default NominationList;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making each person an element in an array (which can have duplicate names), use a hashmap or object.

Here's a quick example I threw together using objects but I suggest hashmaps in the actual implementation

```js
const [nominationGroup, setNominationGroup] = useState({}); 

useEffect(() => {
    let newGroup = {};

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/nominationgroup');
            if (isMounted.current) {
                
                for (const elem of data){
                    if (!newGroup.hasOwnProperty(elem.nomineename)){
                        newGroup[elem.nomineename] = {
                            createdAt: "",
                            description: []
                        };
                    }
                    
                    newGroup[elem.nomineename].description.push(elem.description);
                    newGroup[elem.nomineename].createdAt = elem.createdAt;
                }

                setNominationGroup(newGroup);

                console.log("Nomination data from server :" + res.data);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    fetchData();
    }, []);

return (
    {
        Object.keys(nominationGroup).map(nomineename =>(
            <div className="wrap">
                    <div key={nomineename} id="sidebar-left">
                        {nomineename}
                    </div>

                    <div id="main-content">
                        {
                            nominationGroup[nomineename].description.map(desc => (
                                <li key={desc} className="nomlistdata">{desc}</li>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div key={nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt} id="sidebar-right">
                        {moment(nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}
                    </div>
                <hr></hr>
            </div>
        ))
    }
)
```

Edit: I added an example of how the useEffect hook would look like, adding properties to each person. Since this is an object, there can only be one name per key.

(the added code was written hastily and just concatenates the string. Some more tweaks should be added to fit how you want the data to be displayed)

Comment: Will try and reply

Comment: Sorry this is not working, I am getting numbers 1,2,3... in the ``nomineename `` field

Comment: I have added the screenshot on how the data appears while setting a break point.

Comment: @soccerway nominationGroup should be an object, not an array, and instead of doing `nominationGroup.push(data)` you should do `nominationGroup[name].description.push(data)`. Can you show the code that sets the state?

Comment: I have added the latest full code to the question.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your point. why do we need to push data ?

Comment: @soccerway disregard what I said about pushing data I guessed incorrectly what your useEffect hook looked like before you added it. I edited my post to include an example of what you could do

Comment: This is working now, but Description is now displaying in a single line. I have provided the screenshot to the question. Could that be split into multiple line with 
 ``. Very good sdfsfs.
 . ssbdsdf sfsmfmslfsld``

Comment: done, tell me if that works. All I did was make the description an array and then just iterate through them

Comment: Yes that is now working for me thank you. But I was also having invalid date for that last row only...all other two row above displays correct date...

Comment: what does "date" mean in your data? I can implement a fix where it just assigns the date once or would that not make sense for your data?

Comment: ``createdAt: "2021-06-02T02:42:12.000Z"`` come with full date, I am formatimng it with ``moment(nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')``

Comment: Done. I changed it from concatenating dates to overwriting them. I also included the moment format code. I apologize if this going back and forth is getting tiring by the way, I just want to make sure you have the right fit